# Change encoding of output html file of r markdown

Tags: r, encoding, r-markdown, markdown

I'm writing [r-markdown](/questions/tagged/r-markdown) file, which i `knit` into [html](/questions/tagged/html):

```
title: "Analytics"
author: "John Johnson"
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output: 
    html_notebook: 
      toc: yes
    html_document: 
      toc: yes
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline
```

I am using there some UTF-8 encoding. I have some column names in Russian in data frame and I apply summary to it and want it to be in `html` file after I `knit` it. But after I push `knit` it is being decoded and turns into mess like this:

> `<U+041B><U+043E><U+043A><U+0430><U+0446><U+0438><U+044F>`

How could i fix it? Thanks for your reponse.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")
```

in the setup chunk.

It works when I knit a .md with Russian characters inside a data.frame. This directly comes from this post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-foreign-characters/.